# zf create project project-name creates empty folder

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework, ubuntu-18.04

I am using ZendFramework-1.12.20 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and PHP version is 7.4.
When I run command `zf create project zendtest`, **it creates an empty folder**.

1. I downloaded
   https://packages.zendframework.com/releases/ZendFramework-1.12.20/ZendFramework-1.12.20.tar.gz
2. Extracted the package in /var/www/html/ZendFramework-1.12.20
3. `ln -s /var/www/html/ZendFramework-1.12.20/bin/zf.sh /usr/local/bin/zf`
4. In `/var/www/html/` I execute `"zf create project zendtest"`. **It creates an empty folder.**

I have followed https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html

Please help. It will be really appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using Zend Framwork v1? That version is ancient as they now have version 3 available for PHP 7.4. Also the "Zend" components have been to renamed and moved to [laminas](https://getlaminas.org/). They are no longer supported under the zend namespace, so probably not a good choice if you are creating a new project.

Comment: @AlexP It's client requirement for on-going Live ERP project